# Slightly more complex ManyToMany relationship in Hibernate

Tags: java, database, hibernate, orm

I have the following tables in my database:
Table: entities
Table: countries
Join Table: countries_entities

It's a many-to-many relationship between entities and countries and I have this defined in Entity.hbm.xml like this:

```
<set name="country" table="countries_entities" cascade="all">
   <key column="entity_id" />
      <many-to-many column="country_id" class="pikefin.hibernate.Country" />
</set>
```

Here is the structure of the join table countries_entities:

[image: screenshot]

The default_country field is used to specify a default country when an entity is associated with more than one country. My question is, what is the appropriate way for me to represent this in hibernate? I suppose the brute force way would be to just create an entirely new mapping with a config file of CountryEntity.hbm.xml but I thought there might be a more elegant way by somehow extending the existing many-to-many relationship.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that when you want additional fields, it's helpful to create a secondary class to represent the association:

```
@Embeddable
public class CountryAssociation {
   ...
   private Country country;

   ...
   private boolean defaultCountry;
}
```

And then use @ElementCollection:

```
 @ElementCollection
 @CollectionTable(name = "country_entities", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "entity_id"))    
 private Set<CountryAssociation> countries;
```

I'd also get rid of the id field in the association, as it's not really needed with this type of mapping.

My XML mapping is a little rusty, but you can represent this mapping in xml as well.

I believe the xml would be something like this:

```
<set name="countries" table="country_entities">
  <key column="entity_id" />
  <composite-element class="CountryAssociation">
      <property name="country" />
      <property name="defaultCountry" />
  </composite-element>
</set>
```